# TreeModel backed by Lists

Tags: java, swing, list, tree, treemodel

I want to build a [TreeModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) from some [List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)s that contain the source data. Now, there's an utility class called [DynamicUtilTreeNode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.DynamicUtilTreeNode.html) that can be used to build trees from arrays, Vectors and Hashtables, but... not from Lists?! Of course I could use the List's toArray() method, but it gives a clone array of the List's state at the moment, so any changes in the List wouldn't get propagated to the TreeModel.

Is there an obvious reason why DynamicUtilTreeNode doesn't support Lists? Is there anything similar that would support Lists, or should I just write it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GlazedLists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/) contains everything to build a dynamic tree from lists which automatically updates as you change the lists.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an obvious reason that DynamicUtilTreeNode doesn't support Lists?

It looks as though `DynamicUtilTreeNode` was written before or around the time when the List Collections framework was introduced in Java 1.2.  The Collections that are supported (`Vector` and `Hashtable`) are those that needed to be retrofitted to the `List` interface.  You will notice that `JTable`, as well, makes use of `Vector` and of `Object` arrays in it quick-start constructors.

> s there anything similar that would support Lists, or should I just write it myself?

I dont see anything within the JDK that replaces it with a `List` compatible version.  You might be best served rolling your own.  At the very least, it may give you a better understanding of how the `TreeNode` objects are used.